# Knex SQL Join Multiple Other Tables into Array on First Table

Tags: javascript, sql, knex.js

Currently I'm using Knex to query an MSSQL database. I have a table like this:

## `Meals`

`Id`

## `Vegetables`

`Id`

`Meal` (referencing the Meals table)

## `Fruits`

`Id`

`Meal` (referencing the Meals table)

So one meal ID could have multiple vegetables or fruits. I'm looking to get results with ONE meal id that contains an array of all vegetables, array of all fruits inside the result. Right now using `knex('meals').innerJoin('fruits', 'meals.id', 'fruits.meal')`, I get multiple objects instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you'll definitely get multiple objects with that query. You don't specify what to `SELECT`, so the database returns everything.

The overall schema may not be correct for what (I assume) you're trying to achieve. It seems that you would like an output similar to this?

```
{
  Id: 1, 
  Name: 'Spinach Pie',
  Ingredients: [
    { Id: 1, Name: 'Spinach', Type: 'Vegetable' },
    { Id: 2, Name: 'Garlic', Type: 'Vegetable' }
  ]
}
```

Under your current schema, each vegetable or fruit could have only one meal associated with it. This is a HAS ONE relationship: "a vegetable has one meal". Obviously, we can use any given vegetable in all kinds of different dishes, so we need to think about the problem differently. The correct way to think about it is, a vegetable HAS MANY meals, and a meal HAS MANY vegetables. This leads us to a structure with a join table:

```
Meals
 - Id
 - Name

Ingredients
 - Id
 - Name
 - Type

MealsIngredients
 - Id
 - Meal
 - Ingredient
```

(I wouldn't necessarily write a real recipe book this way, but for demonstration purposes...)

This would give us a query like so:

```
knex('Meals')
  .select('Meals.Name as mealName', 'Ingredients.*')
  .innerJoin('MealsIngredients', 'Meals.Id', 'MealsIngredients.Meal')
  .innerJoin('Ingredients', 'Ingredients.Id', 'MealsIngredients.Ingredient')
  .where('Meals.Id', mealId)
```

It doesn't get you where you want, but to this point:

```
[
  { mealName: 'Spinach Pie', Id: 1, Name: 'Spinach', Type: 'Vegetable' },
  { mealName: 'Spinach Pie', Id: 2, Name: 'Garlic', Type: 'Vegetable' }
]
```

To combine this with the meal's details, there are several options. We could issue two separate queries, or some kind of array aggregate (I'm not really familiar with SQL Server's options there). Given the relatively simple requirement here, you could probably just assemble the object you're after in JS:

```
const outputFormatter = (output, ingredient) => {
  output.name = ingredient.mealName
  if (!output.ingredients) {
    output.ingredients = []
  }
  const { mealName, ...theIngredient } = ingredient
  output.ingredients.push(...theIngredient)
  return output
}

knex('Meals')
  .select('Meals.Name as mealName', 'Ingredients.*')
  .innerJoin('MealsIngredients', 'Meals.Id', 'MealsIngredients.Meal')
  .innerJoin('Ingredients', 'Ingredients.Id', 'MealsIngredients.Ingredient')
  .where('Meals.Id', mealId)
  .then(records => records.reduce(outputFormatter, {}))
```

This would yield:

```
{
  name: 'Spinach Pie',
  ingredients: [
    { Id: 1, Name: 'Spinach', Type: 'Vegetable' },
    { Id: 2, Name: 'Garlic', Type: 'Vegetable' }
  ]
}
```

I may have lapsed somewhat with capitalisation... I'm not used to PascalCase!